# Copying polygon geometry in ArcPy using old style cursor?

Tags: arcpy, polygon

What I need to do is to create a copy of a polygon shapefile to a new shapefile with slightly different attributes.

Where I got stuck is in copying the geometry - Geometry doesn't have to change at all in the new shapefile. The actual 'copying' of the polygon geometry is not the problem.
I loop through the input shapefile:

```
> for row in rows:
>     partnum = 0
>     feat=row.getValue("SHAPE")
```

And then I enter this shape in the output feature class:

```
outFeat.Shape=feat
```

Problem is, I also want to calculate the Area, Perimeter and centroid of the polygon and I can't seem to 'cast' the ***feat*** variable to a polygon so I can then get the polygon properties (area, centroid, etc). Can you do that somehow?

One of the things I tried was to create the polygon from scratch, i.e. loop though the vertices of the input polygon and create a new polygon/array to use for the new polygon. This method apart from being IMO over the top, it also had the problems with the multi-part polygons. My polygons ended up corrupted - although I followed the steps outlined [here](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/18985-Bug-Creating-polygons-with-holes-using-Arcpy?p=61005&posted=1#post61005)

I didn't dwell too much with it since what I did instead is create a dummy Polygon which I then passed to it the current geometry value in the cursor.

```
# Create a dummy polygon
            dummyArray=arcpy.Array()
            dummyPoint = arcpy.Point()
            coordList = [[[1,2], [2,4], [3,7]],[[6,8], [5,7], [7,2], [9,5]]]
            for feature in coordList:
                for coordPair in feature:
                    dummyPoint.X = coordPair[0]
                    dummyPoint.Y = coordPair[1]
                    dummyArray.add(dummyPoint)
                dummyArray.add(dummyArray.getObject(0))

            parcel=arcpy.Polygon(dummyArray)
            parcel=feat ### --> This is where I replace the dummy geometry value with the current value in the loop
            parcel_c=arcpy.Point()
            parcel_c=parcel.centroid # I can now get to the polygon properties
            c_x=parcel_c.X
            c_y=parcel_c.Y
```

Although this works fine, I am not really happy with it as its a bit of a hacking and -as mentioned in the beginning- I think I am missing something vital!

Any insights?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're pretty close with your first script, you have to jump one more hurdle to access the geometry object.  Here's the ESRI help docs on [working with geometry in Python](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000001s000000)

The key is here:

> shapeName = arcpy.Describe(inFeatures).shapeFieldName

Once you have a handle for the object you can use it like in your script, and you'll have access to all of the polygon properties that you're after.

```
for row in rows:
    partnum = 0
    feat=row.getValue(shapeName)
```

Comment: So thats what the .shapeFieldName does! :-) I thought it was only for getting the spatial column name at runtime... I knew I was missing something! Many thanks again @Roy !