# Copying polygon features with WHERE clause using arcpy.da?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, cursor

This question is similar to [Copy a polygon geometry in Arcpy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30271/copy-a-polygon-geometry-in-arcpy), except within the context of using Arcpy.da instead.

I want to copy the geometry from one feature class to another using ArcPy.da (I'm not concerned about attributes of the feature class right now).

I have a Python script that reads features from one feature class based upon a given WHERE clause using a search cursor and then inserts the features from the search cursor into another feature class:

```
import arceditor
import arcpy


inputfeatureclass = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
insert_field = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
where_field = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
expression = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
insertfeatureclass = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)


def get_specified_rows(inputfeatureclass, insert_field, where_field, expression):

    searchcursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inputfeatureclass, (insert_field, where_field), where_clause=expression) 

    return searchcursor

def insert_specified_rows(searchcursor, insertfeatureclass):

    insertcursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(insertfeatureclass, ("SHAPE@"))
    for row in searchcursor:
        arcpy.AddMessage(row[0])
        insertcursor.insertRow(row[0])

searchcursor = get_specified_rows(inputfeatureclass, insert_field, where_field, expression)
insert_specified_rows(searchcursor, insertfeatureclass)
```

The polygon **Shape** field is the value passed for my insert_field parameter.

The program fails on insertcursor.insertRow(row[0]) with the following error: [sequence size must match size of the row.](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/40604)

I'm getting the following message on arcpy.AddMessage(row[0]): **[3088680.146493972, 10159411.210196389]**.

This does not look like a polygon array, perhaps I am reading the polygon incorrectly using my search cursor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would restructure to avoid defining functions. I'm not sure they play nicely with arcpy.da cursors. Here's my suggestion:

```
import arceditor
import arcpy


inputfeatureclass = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
expression = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
insertfeatureclass = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)


with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(insertfeatureclass, ("SHAPE@")) as i_cursor:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inputfeatureclass, ("SHAPE@"), where_clause=expression) as s_cursor:
        for s_row in s_cursor:
            i_cursor.insertRow(s_row)
```

I removed the search cursor's reference to `insert_field` and `where_field` because I can't see their relevance to simply copying the geometry.

Comment: Works perfect. And you're right - those two parameters are not relevant to simply copying geometry. I had placed them in anticipation for other things outside of the scope of this question and forgot to take them out before I posted. You had one extra parenthesis in your syntax, I've edited to remove it and all extraneous information for a nice clear and concise answer.

Comment: Also I'll add that the error I was getting hints that these references to insert_field and where_field were likely the issue. Thanks!